# Most general Green-Kubo relation for transport coefficient - $\beta/V$ dependence of diffusion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion, viscosity

Hansen & McDonald write that a the most general Green-Kubo formula for some microscopic dynamical variable $A$ can be written as:

$K=\frac{\beta}{V} \int_0^\infty \bigg\langle \dot{A}(t) \cdot \dot{A}(0)\bigg\rangle \mathrm{d}t$. (Eq.  8.4.17, Theory of Simple Liquids, 3rd Edition)

Though any transport coefficient K is related to an time autocorrelation function including $\frac{\beta}{V}$ with $\beta=\frac{1}{k_\mathrm{B}T}$ the the volume $V$.

This is well reflected in the formula for the viscosity (and heat conductivity), e.g.,

$\eta_\mathrm{shear} = \frac{\beta}{V} \int_0^\infty \bigg\langle \Pi_{ij}(t) \cdot \Pi_{ij}(0)\bigg\rangle \mathrm{d}t$

with the stress tensor $\Pi$, consisting of the sum of kinetic energy tensor and the virial tensor. The shear viscosity can be computed using a single or an average over the three components with $i\ne j$ (and two differences between the square of diagonal elements).

But how can I see this for the for the diffusion?

There we have

$D = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^\infty \langle \vec{v}(t)\cdot\vec{v}(0)\rangle dt$

Can someone shed some light on this?